# How to use AspectJ to create a pointcut to capture multiple parameter group Scala function

Tags: scala, aspectj

I like to write a pointcut for the following Scala function...

```
package org.test.scala.aspect

object Something {
    def process[B <: Command: ClassTag](payload: PayloadObject)(f: B => Behavior[Message]): 
       Behavior[Message] = {
       ....
       }
    }
}
```

and the aspect

```
@Aspect
public class SomethingAspect {
   @Around("execution(org.test.scala.aspect.* *.*(..))")
   public Object invoke(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
      //do something
   }
}
```

My AspectJ experience is mainly Java based, so considering Java does not have such method declarations but considering at the end of the day the byte code that Scala produces is Java compatible it should be theoretically possible to write a pointcut for it or?

If it is, how are we going to access to the 2 parameter groups in the pointcut...

Thx for answers...

Comment: I have zero Scala knowledge, just am a kind of AspectJ expert. I don't even understand the syntax of your code snippet. Maybe I can help you if you show the output which `javap` or a decompiler produce when inspecting your Scala class (make sure the aspect is not enabled for compilation). It may also give you a clue as to what to look for.

Comment: Ok,  first of thx for help offer and I will try to provide the information you require....but if you want to understand concept in the above snippet you can check the following link I always found that helpful https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/how-to-write-functions-multiple-parameter-groups

Comment: Thanks, but you don't expect me to learn Scala for the purpose of answering a single question, do you? Even if I did, I cannot just copy & paste your code and compile it because your code is just fragments. ;-)

Comment: It was not there for you to learn Scala, I thought you like the understand the Scala structure (which is weird for Java point of view) and this blog explains it really good....

Comment: No problem, I think I kinda understand it now. But still I don't know what the compiler makes of it. What about the information I asked for? Or did you find the solution by yourself already? Maybe an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which I could copy, compile and run on my own machine would be nice. Feel free to edit your question or push the MCVE to GitHub, I can take a look then.